# Log and file Auditing

Tags: pci-dss

I am going through this PCI compliance for the first time. I have some questions because it is not clear what they are expecting and maybe I am over thinking it.

**Question 1:** 10.3.1 through 10.7 Access tracking

You are supposed to log every time a user elevates their permissions to perform a task and log what task was, who it was, date time, and why.

Does this mean all PCs and Servers? Or is this just server? Or is this just the PCs we have in the call center that take credit card info and the server they communicate with?

**Question 2:** 11.5 File integrity monitoring.

Is this just the PCs in the call center and the server they communicate with? or is this everything? Obviously, I would like to have everything but that is a lot of data to go through every day. Or my Splunk account needs a serious upgrade on data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logging and FIM must be enabled on all systems within the in-scope network segments. If you've a call centre, this will mean at least the users' desktops as well as the servers supporting the infrastructure. Ideally, your customer service agents won't have administrative profiles on their systems so the number of logs you'll receive related to privilege escalation will be limited.

While Splunk agents will gather and ship logs for central analysis, it's not really a File Integrity Monitoring solution. You could use software like OSSEC or Wazuh or implement similar functionality using Microsoft's AppLocker which would allow you whitelist applications and monitor changes.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly our call center (which is subnetted off) are the only PCs I need to monitor for FIM? We have OSSEC but how does that help with log files for privilege escalation? Do I not need to harvest those windows logs for review some how?

Comment: The subnet containing supporting infrastructure servers - authorisation, anti-virus etc - also needs logging and FIM to be in place. OSSEC should be forwarding your Windows event logs - these should include privilege escalation. If not, you may need to edit the GPO used by those endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting up your log collection? You can use something like NXLog (there is a free edition) that can log these types of user events (ie Security EventLog events) and there are some modules for file integrity monitoring.

Comment: We already have OSSEC. I did not set it up but now that I know it has more feature than file system monitoring I will learn more a get it working.